# Mapping location in MySQL

Tags: mysql, location, latitude-longitude

I have two tables:

1) One is the location table that is kept from android phone consists of username, latitude, longitude, date, time.

2) Another one is table that I kept country, region, province, postal code, city, latitude, longitude.

**I want to mapping location(lat,lng) of table 1) using table 2) before insert to db.** 
It's look simple but the problem is location of table 2) is just a stable point, otherwise the location of table 1) are points which traversal of each city. 
So, the location of table 1) **is not similar** to location of table 2).

Any one have idea for this problem ? Any formula or technique ?
Appreciate your help.

**edit: I tried this statement before insert statement**

```
$city  =  mysql_query("SELECT p.city
    FROM place AS p
    ORDER BY ACOS(SIN(p.lng)*SIN('".$lng."')+COS(p.lng)*COS('".$lng."')*COS(p.lat-'".$lat."'))",$con);
```

but the result is `Resource id #3` in the field, other fields also shown like this.
c

Comment: For each point in table 1, find the closest location in table 2 by ordering by the least distance between the latitude/longitude pairs. You can look up how to calculate spherical distance in your favorite geometry text book or search engine. Just plug the formula into your query.

Comment: This formula : d = acos ( sin(x1) * sin(x2) + cos(x1) * cos(x2) * cos(y2- y1) ) * r, right? I will try, thanks.

Comment: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html

Comment: @Dan Grossman: I used this formula but the result is look strange. Please see above, and please tell me what is/are my mistake(s). Appreciate that.

Comment: "Resource id #3", mysql_query return a resource, then you use $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource) to read a line form that resource, and then you got your data in $row['city']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so somthing like:

```
SELECT regions.*
FROM users, regions
WHERE users.user_id = $user_id
ORDER BY 
  ACOS ( 
    SIN(users.long) * SIN(regions.long) + 
    COS(users.long) * COS(regions.long) * COS(regions.lat - users.lat) 
  )
LIMIT 1
```

**Added 2011-08-15**

or in php like your exemple

```
$query  = "SELECT city
           FROM place
           ORDER BY
             ACOS(
               SIN(lng) * SIN({$lng}) +
               COS(lng) * COS({$lng}) * COS(lat - {$lat})
             )";
$resource = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
$city = $result['city'];
```

Comment: @Puggen Se : I tried it but the result is not the same that I expected. Please see my edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for every help.

```
$qc = mysql_query("SELECT *
    FROM place AS p
    ORDER BY MIN(ACOS(SIN(p.lng)*SIN({$lng})+COS(p.lng)*COS({$lng})*COS(p.lat-{$lat})))", $con);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qc)) {
    $city = $row['city'];
    $district = $row['district'];
    $province = $row['province'];
    $region = $row['region'];
    $country = $row['country'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $username . "_logs_" . $type . "(username,date,
                time,lat,lng,city,district,province,region,country,note,color)
                VALUES('".$username."','".$date."','".$time."',
                '".$lat."','".$lng."','".$city."','".$district."'
                ,'".$province."','".$region."','".$country."','unknown','unknown')", $con)
            or die("Cannot Insert to Table");
    mysql_close();
}
```

This is my final answer. I want to share for whoever weak in query like me :))